# UIView Constraint not working on iPhone 3.5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, constraints

I am animating a constraint on an iOS7 app. On the iPhone 4" screen it works, but the same code on an iPhone 3.5" does not work. Both are running iOS7. I have no clue why it works on one size phone but not the other?

```
-(void)showBottomRequestView {

[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Ensures that all pending layout operations have been completed

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.3 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut) animations:^{

    self.qBottomConstraint.constant = 65; <-- this UIView only works on  4.0"
    self.meBottomConstraint.constant = 65; <-- this UIButton works on 3.5" and 4.0"

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //
}];

}
```

Comment: Can you post all of your constraints?

Comment: Why don't you log the constraint constants before you kick off the animation?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could that `UIView` constraint value is already what you are trying to animate it to ... You can place it within 3.5" area of the screen for both 4" and 3.5" sizes and see if it works correctly for both sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but I added another constraint and did an if/else.

```
if(3.5) 
  do 3.5 constraint

else 
  do 4.0 constraint
```